# Custom script in electorn builder?

Tags: javascript, installation, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I'm working on an Electron application and am using electron-builder to generate a windows installer and dmg for mac.

Everything works great, I was able to set up auto update and use other features of electron-builder.

Now I need to include other files that are not part of my electron project and execute them in order to install them during the installation process (on windows).

From the electron builder docs (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#NsisOptions) I found out that a custom script can be used (NSIS, which I'll have to learn). I've tried including a test script but nothing seems to happen, has anyone here tried this?

The docs don't seem detailed enough in that regard so it's been very confusing.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should probably include the test script you're attempting to use in your post.

Comment: The NSIS code itself is irrelevant, my issue is that it does not get executed or included, it's with electron builder itself, I want to hear from somebody that has actually done this and see if there is something I'm not seeing and if my assumption that a custom script can be included is correct.

Comment: Also I want to know if the custom script has more to do with the process of building the installer or the process of installing my application, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at different places I found out that setting win.target to nsis and perMachine to true will generate the NSIS installer.

It does work, but then sadly there are no auto updates.